# nsIFile: How to get Vista AppData/LocalLow folder path?

Tags: firefox-addon, xpcom

I am able to get path to User 'AppData/Local' folder as follows,
appdatafile = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/directory_service;1"].
                      getService(Components.interfaces.nsIProperties).
                      get("LocalAppData", Components.interfaces.nsIFile).path;

Can anyone help me to get the 'AppData/LocalLow' user folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no named constant to get it, so you'd have to get AppData first (pass in `AppData` instead of `LocalAppData`), and append `LocalLow` on the object.

You could/should also [file a bug to request this constant](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?alias=&assigned_to=nobody%40mozilla.org&blocked=&bug_file_loc=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F1152005%2Fnsifile-how-to-get-vista-appdata-locallow-folder-path&bug_severity=normal&bug_status=NEW&cc=jmathies%40mozilla.com&cf_blocking_191=---&cf_blocking_fennec=---&comment=&component=XPCOM&contenttypeentry=&contenttypemethod=autodetect&contenttypeselection=text%2Fplain&data=&dependson=&description=&flag_type-203=X&flag_type-270=X&flag_type-271=X&flag_type-325=X&flag_type-369=X&flag_type-37=X&flag_type-370=X&flag_type-385=X&flag_type-4=X&flag_type-422=X&flag_type-479=X&flag_type-480=X&flag_type-485=X&flag_type-486=X&flag_type-5=X&flag_type-518=X&flag_type-519=X&flag_type-529=X&flag_type-530=X&flag_type-535=X&form_name=enter_bug&keywords=&maketemplate=Remember%20values%20as%20bookmarkable%20template&op_sys=Windows%20Vista&priority=--&product=Core&qa_contact=xpcom%40core.bugs&rep_platform=All&short_desc=nsIFile%20should%20have%20a%20constant%20for%20%22AppData%2FLocalLow%22&target_milestone=---&version=Trunk).